# Android: How to press two physical buttons at same time programatically

Tags: android

I am trying to press two physical button at same time with code, but I am able to deal with only 1 button. Here is the code:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();

                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN);//this is 1 button 



                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

How can I write code to press 2 buttons at same time?

Comment: have you tried adding same line for the second button?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes. but it didn't work

Comment: how exactly it didn't work?

Comment: Which buttons do you want to press? What are you trying to achieve in the end? Let us know because there may be a better solution :)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the first button remaines pressed.

Comment: @MinasMina I want to press powerbutton and down volume key programatically

Comment: looks like you want to make a screenshot, right?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes. But not of view of my application

Comment: then you can't. And should not be able to. Just imagine what a security issue would it be if any app could take a screenshot of entire screen at any time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from the comments it seems you actually want to take a screenshot. Please state exactly your problem next time, don't make people guess.

As for your question, it actually seems to be possible using the `MediaProjectionManager` and a service. See [this example project on github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture).

This only works on Android 5.0+.